# Operation on Elements of Edge Space

Tags: graph-theory

I try to figure out the strange operation on two element $F$ and $F'$ of the edge space.

The operation was introduced in textbook Graph Theory by Diestel.

Given two elements $F, F'$ of the edge space, viewed as function $E\rightarrow F_2$, we write
$\left \langle F,F' \right \rangle:=\sum _{e \in E} F(e)F'(e) \in F_2$.

> At first it looks very reasonable, as I understood $F(e)$ is 1 if $e$ contains in $F$, so the result is the number of the common edges of $F$ and $F'$ .

This is zero if and only if $F$ and $F'$ have an even number of edges in common; in particular, we have $\left \langle F,F' \right \rangle = 0 $ with $F \neq 0$.

> It contradicts to my assumption! Why it is actually true?

Comment: Do you know what $F_2$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$, particularly $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Moreover, if you add an even number of $1$'s you will obtain $0$.

Your observation is correct in some sense: $\sum_{e\in E}F(e)F'(e)$ will be $1$ added $|F\cap F'|$ times. Keeping in mind that in $\mathbb{F}_2$ adding $1$ an even number of times gives $0$. Therefore if $|F\cap F'|$ is even then $\langle F,F'\rangle=0$. (Similarly, if $|F\cap F'|$ is odd, then $\langle F,F'\rangle=1$.)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!